# Aeron basic pub/sub pair connects on same host, fails across hosts

Tags: java, multicastsocket, aeron

I am running the BasicPublisher/BasicSubscriber pair from https://github.com/real-logic/aeron binding them to the same multicast group+port. When they run on the same host they connect, but when they run on separate hosts (same switch+subnet+vlan) the publisher reports "Offer failed because publisher is not connected to subscriber”. Here are my configurations:

AERON PAIR:

```
java -Daeron.sample.channel="aeron:udp?endpoint=225.10.9.7:4050" \
-Daeron.sample.embeddedMediaDriver=true \
-cp ./aeron-all/build/libs/aeron-all-1.29.1-SNAPSHOT.jar \
io.aeron.samples.BasicPublisher
```

```
java -Daeron.sample.channel="aeron:udp?endpoint=225.10.9.7:4050" \
-Daeron.sample.embeddedMediaDriver=true \
-cp ./aeron-all/build/libs/aeron-all-1.29.1-SNAPSHOT.jar \
io.aeron.samples.BasicSubscriber
```

I ran an iperf udp pair on the same hosts binding to the same group+port, which I think proves that the switch is not blocking the multicast traffic. My hope is that I’m just using Aeron incorrectly; or perhaps there's some other networking issue I can check?

IPERF PAiR:

```
iperf -c 225.10.9.7 -p 4050 -u -T 32 -t 300 -I 1 -b 1G
[  3] 46.0-47.0 sec   128 MBytes  1.07 Gbits/sec
…
```

```
iperf -s -u -B 225.10.9.7 -p 4050 -I 1 -b 1G
[  3] 45.0-46.0 sec   128 MBytes  1.07 Gbits/sec   0.001 ms   35/91304 (0.038%)
…
```

Java: java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64

OS: Centos7 3.10.0-514.26.2.el7.x86_64

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using multicast endpoints it is also necessary to provide the interface for some operating systems when going remote. The interface can have a mask to simplify configuration for all machines on a subnet. For example:

```
aeron:udp?endpoint=224.0.1.1:40456|interface=192.168.1.4
aeron:udp?endpoint=224.0.1.1:40456|interface=192.168.1.0/24
```

https://github.com/real-logic/aeron/wiki/Channel-Configuration

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense -- the hosts I was testing on are on multiple networks. I can't reach the environment to verify at the moment but will at the nearest opportunity.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and it was fixed by adding a **ttl** config option something like this

```
aeron:udp?endpoint=224.0.1.1:40456|interface=192.168.1.4|ttl=16
aeron:udp?endpoint=224.0.1.1:40456|interface=192.168.1.0/24|ttl=16
```